# Dirty Checks: JSF + Primefaces application?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have web application in which I am using JSF + Primefaces for UI. I am facing difficulty in applying dirty checks on web pages specially when working with AJAX calls like AJAX call on rowSelect event of datatable.

Following is the exact scenario in which I want to apply dirty checks with AJAX call. Following are the components which I am using in my web page.

1) I have one dataTable which is populated by bean named 'companyBean' (Having attributes for companies)

```
<p:dataTable id="basic" var="company" value="#{companyInfoBean.companyList}" 
    rowKey="#{company.id}"
    selection="#{companyInfoBean.selectedCompany}" selectionMode="single">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":customerDataForm:customerDataFields" />

    <p:column id="modelHeader">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Company Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{company.companyName}" />
    </p:column>
      more columns....
</p:dataTable>
```

As depicted above on row selected **(AJAX Call)** I  update the values in the form on the bottom of the page

```
<h:form id="customerDataForm">
<p:panel id="customerDataFields">
<p:panelGrid >
<p:row>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputLabel for="companyname" value="Company Name " />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText id="companyname" value="#{companyInfoBean.selectedCompany.companyName}" label="Company Name" />
    </p:column>
         more columns...
  <p:row>
    <p:column colspan="2" style="text-align:right">
        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{companyInfoBean.updateCompany}" 
        update=":customerDataForm:customerDataTable"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column colspan="2" style="text-align:left">
        <p:commandButton value="Undo" />
    </p:column>
</p:row>
```

In above form user can Edit the values that is updated on the rowSelect on datatable.

**Now I want a dirty check on the form on the rowSelection on the datatable** i.e. if there are some unsaved changes on form that user used be prompted in spite of execution of AJAX call of rowSelect..

Basically what I can understand from this scenario.. that I need some conditional based AJAX calls rather then straightforward. Or I have to use some jQuery stuff to get dirty checks implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you can implement this. Here are a few (I would prefer Method 3 if popup's are OK):

#### Method 1:

a) Use a copy of selectedCompany eg, editCompanyBean as the backing
    bean for customerDataFields.
 b) Add a "listener" to the ajax event
    this can check the editCompanyBean for null values before setting
    this with selectedCompany's values. If this fails you can growl a
    message and block the copy. 
    Note: You can use an override switch to override (b)
 c) On save of editCompanyBean initialize it to null
    values for fields.

#### Method 2:

a) In the set statement for selectedCompany check if the bean already has a value   populated. Throw a warning message if its populated and skip edit.
 b) Have the user click save or reset on  customerDataFields before proceeding.
    Note: Clear selectedCompany after each save or reset of customerDataFields

#### Method 3:

a) Put customerDataFields in a modal popup dialog. Set it up so that the user has to save or reset before proceeding.
 
b) The ajax event will popup the above modal dialog. You can use a button to popup as well.